# Adding Model State error when exception is thrown during TryUpdateModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Is it possible to add model state error message during updating properties using TryUpdateModel? I would like to detect if exception was throw during updating one of my (view)model properties and if so I would like to add model state error message.

I would like to do something like this:

```
throw new ValidationException("some message");
```

and then I would like to display the message without having to explicitly setting:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", exception.Message);
```

in my controller.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

TryUpdateModel already adds modelstate errors for each validation failure it encounters.

Comment: but how do I display error message from ValidationException? Error message property is left blank

Comment: You could use the `Html.ValidationSummary` helper or `Html.ValidationMessageFor` for individual properties.

Comment: the problem is how to set error.ErrorMessage of this custom ValidationException, becuse now the massage is contained in error.Exception.Message which is not being displayed.

Comment: Who throws this custom `ValidationException`? You need to write a custom validation attribute and override the IsValid method. Otherwise the TryUpdateModel won't add the error in the modelstate.

Comment: Me, it doesn't come from data attributes. And i can't use attributes here because it has complicated validation logic during evaluating actual work. I'm not validating this before or after work but during, the concrete example is adding licenses to users from company licenses pool, if i run out of licenses component which I am using is throwing exception, I can wrap it in validation exception and I would like to display error message.

Comment: In this case it is up to you to manually add the error into the ModelState.

Comment: ok, thx u for your help, I thought there is a way to do it automatically since attributes are actually adding those messages.